# Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu, partitioning small SSD and HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I looked at several related questions because some questions remained for me.

I have just bought a Asus Ultrabook with Windows 8 pre-installed, 500gb HDD and 24gb SSD. Apparently (according to some other answers to related questions) Windows is installed in the 24gb SSD because it boots very fast. I intend to follow this tutorial http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html but I have few questions about the outcome and process.

First, Can I install only Ubuntu in the SSD (considering I'm novice and didn't find any specific tutorial) and keep windows in the HDD, does worth doing that ? I intend to use MatLab, Python (I'm still novice at Python too, so nothing demanding), Mathematica and others, in Windows I need to use AutoCad 2d and some other similar programs. If I do install Ubuntu in SSD, would it be "painful" to access bios as it is with Windows ? (I can't access directly pressing F2, I need to follow some steps and then restart twice the computer.) 
Then, assuming everything above is ok, does that tutorial works for my case ? He shrinks partitions on Windows, could it result in a problem since "Windows is installed in the SSD"?

Obs: I'm assuming that SSD couldn't have Windows and Ubuntu since it is too small.

Comment: Windows is probably not on SSD, but you have Intel SRT or similar technology used as cache to make Windows boot fast. It may only be using as much space as you have RAM. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/what-is-intel-rapid-start-technology If you change from Intel SRT to AHCI mode for drives and follow all the other standard UEFI install instructions, especially those for a second drive, you should be ok. Be sure to fully backup Windows & efi partition and make a full set of DVDs from restore partition.

Comment: Your F2 key might work if you give yourself a "normal" vs "fast" boot speed (or some value greater than 0). Timing is everything, but maybe holding the key down would work too (or might produce a "stuck key" error).

Comment: Ok Thanks !, but I am about to start it and I noticed that in the tutorial he shrinks the partiton OS (c:) , but the partition Data(D:) is larger in my computer, may I shrink them both ? does it change anything during further installation process ?

Comment: Best to only shrink one or the other. And you must immediately reboot and run chkdsk. Not sure if Windows will auto run chkdsk on d: drive partition. Only use Windows tools on the NTFS partitions. If you do shink both you probably need to move partition which is a bit more risky. In all cases good backup are vital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't do it!

Leave the SSD alone and install on the HDD.  Then use [`bcache`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache) to use the 24GB HDD as a cache for the HDD just like Windows uses [SRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology)!

Follow this advice: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu on the small SSD. I did that, but that small SSD isn't very reliable. It is already going bad for me, it has many bad sectors. I wouldn't recommend it honestly.